# Multiple Threads within application

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am working on an application and I would like to create multiple timers that all fire at different intervals. On each fire I would like them to call a relevant function.

Initially, I would like a timer that fire every 100ms, 1 second, 10 second, 30second ect.
On each "tick" I would like to call a function that reads data from a device and stores it in a buffer.

What is the best way to create the required timers and handle their events?

EDIT 
I have done something similar to this for each timer, but it's cumbersome, so looking for something simpler/smarter.

```
'Variables

Dim Timer100msUpdateInterval As DateInterval = 100
Dim Timer100msUpdate As Threading.Timer

'On Load
Dim TimerCallBack100ms As Threading.TimerCallback = New Threading.TimerCallback(AddressOf Timer100msUpdateTimerEvent)
Timer100msUpdate = New Threading.Timer(TimerCallBack100ms, Nothing, 100, Timer100msUpdateInterval)

'For each timer
Private Sub Timer100msUpdateTimerEvent(ByVal state As Object)
    do100msTimerStuff()
End Sub
```

I like the concept approach by @kiLLua, but need some way to identify when each timer fires, which timer ran

Comment: We're not really a code designing/writing service. It's best if you come here once you've begun writing your own code and you get stuck. Then you can post your code with a specific question. In the meanwhile, have you tried a google search on this?

Comment: If you want to use two timers then you do whatever you would do for one timer but you do it twice.  If you don't know how to use one timer then you should be researching that first.

Comment: Your question makes it sound like you're calling the same method on each timer, but that wouldn't make sense as the 100ms timer would fire whenever any of the others do. What are you actually trying to do with each of the timers?

Comment: @Enigmativity, Each timer will be updating a group of values form a device. The group is different for each timere. The above code is currently one of multipl timers (have about 6) but it's not ideal as it requires code change each time i want to create a new timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dim timers As New List(Of System.Threading.Timer)
    timers.Add(New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf MyHandler, Nothing, 100, 100))
    timers.Add(New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf MyHandler, Nothing, 1000, 1000))
    timers.Add(New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf MyHandler, Nothing, 10000, 10000))
    timers.Add(New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf MyHandler, Nothing, 30000, 30000))
```

where handler is defined as.

```
Sub MyHandler(state As Object)

End Sub
```

If your device cannot have 2 simultaneous requests then you'll need to implement some locking in MyHandler.

---

```
timers.Add(New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf MyHandler, myDataRow, 30000, 30000))

Sub MyHandler(state As Object)
     dim row = CType(state, DataRow)
     ...
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking along these lines. How can i determine though which timer called the MyHandled? Each timer will call a different function

Comment: If you need that then just change `AddressOf MyHandler` to `AddressOf HandlerForTimer1` ... etc. And have 4 different handlers.

Comment: Thanks, What about if i wanted to create the timers dynamically from a list in the database. I can loop through the result data and create/add timers to the list. but how do i manage creating the multiple addressof items for each timer?

Comment: For this approach go back to having one handler. The second parameter to the constructor is any variable you'd like. In this case you'd pass your database record or something similar. Then in the MyHandler you can just cast state to your object type and use that data to do your specific handling.

Comment: Awesome. This is what i was chasing for this. I'm passing the "ID" of the frequency as the second parameter and then based on that I know the timer that is firing.

Answer (score 0):

Use Time interval

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ' Do What you want here
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    ' Do What you want here
End Sub

' Have a private sub that handles each tick ..

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Timer1.Interval = 100   ' 100 ms
    Timer2.Interval = 1000  ' 1 seconds
    Timer3.Interval = 10000 ' 10 seconds
    Timer4.Interval = 30000 ' 30 seconds
    Timer1.Start() : Timer2.Start() : Timer3.Start() : Timer4.Start()
End Sub
```

There you go .. You can start from here..

Comment: Thanks. What i'm trying to avoid is hardcoding that values. I would like to eventually go through and create everything in code loaded from a database